# How to send a complete email using smtplib python

Tags: python, email, mime, smtplib

I am trying to send an email using Python `smtplib`.

My objective is to include the below info in email

1. Attachment file  `#works fine`
2. Paste the contents of a table in message body `#works fine`
3. Write a few lines about the table (as text) in message body `# not works. instead stores as an attachment`

So, I tried the below code

```
message = MIMEMultipart()
message['Subject'] = 'For your review - files'
message['From'] = 'user2@org.com'
message['To'] = 'user1@org.com'
# code to paste table contents in outlook message window - works fine
body_content = output # this has the pretty table - html table
message.attach(MIMEText(body_content, "html"))
# code to paste the written text in outlook message window - not works. instead of writing the text in outlook body,it stores as an attachment
written_text = """\
    Hi,
    How are you?"""
message.attach(MIMEText(written_text, "plain"))
# code to attach an csv file to a outlook email - works fine
with open(filename, "rb") as attachment:
    part = MIMEBase("application", "octet-stream")
    part.set_payload(attachment.read())
    encoders.encode_base64(part)
part.add_header(
"Content-Disposition",
f"attachment; filename= {filename}",
)
message.attach(part)
msg_body = message.as_string()
server = SMTP('internal.org.com', 2089)
server.sendmail(message['From'], message['To'], msg_body)
print("mail sent successfully")
server.quit()
```

The problem in my code is that it creates a text file (containing the message "Hi, How are you") and sends as an attachment?

But I want "Hi, How are you" as a text message in the main Outlook message window.

Comment: Is this question useful for you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362600/how-to-send-email-attachments

Comment: @GonzaloOdiard - Thanks for theblink.As you can see in my code, I already have everything done as provided in other link. But the problem is, since I have two seperate parts to body followed by attachment section, it treats my 2nd body part as attachment as well. Is this something you can help me resolve please?

Comment: @TheGreat Your email needs to be MIMEMultipart.

Comment: @Oli - you can see at the top of my code that I have already used MIMEMultipart. If possible, can write as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate problem is that many email clients assume that text body parts after the first are attachments. You can experiment with adding an explicit `Content-Disposition: inline` to the part(s) you want rendered as part of the main message, but is there a reason these need to be separate body parts in the first place? Combining the text fragments into a single body part would perhaps make more sense here.

More fundamentally, your `email` code was written for an older Python version. The `email` module in the standard library was overhauled in Python 3.6 to be more logical, versatile, and succinct; new code should target the (no longer very) new `EmailMessage` API. Probably throw away this code and start over with modern code from [the Python `email` examples documentation.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html)

```
from email.message import EmailMessage

message = EmailMessage()
message['Subject'] = 'For your review - files'
message['From'] = 'user2@org.com'
message['To'] = 'user1@org.com'

message.set_content(output, subtype="html")

written_text = """\
    Hi,
    How are you?"""
message.add_attachment(
    written_text, subtype="plain",
    disposition="inline")

with open(filename, "rb") as attachment:
    message.add_attachment(
        attachment.read(),
        maintype="application", subtype="octet-stream",
        filename=filename)

with SMTP('internal.org.com', 2089) as server:
    server.send_message(message)
    print("mail sent successfully")
    server.quit()
```

If the final attachment is really a CSV file, specifying it as `application/octet-stream` is a bit misleading; the proper MIME type would be `text/csv` (see also [What MIME type should I use for CSV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076042/what-mime-type-should-i-use-for-csv))

Comment: but the problem is when I use send_message, it has prpblem sending it to multiple receipients. It doesn't send to them

Comment: Your example only shows one recipient. A common solution is `message["To"] = ", ".join(["recipient@example.net", "other@example.org"])`